# Canvas - How to rotate vertical/horizontal image correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation, html5-canvas

I've looked at many of the rotate canvas/scaling canvas resolved issues, but the solutions didn't really solve this issue, so still unsure how to get it to work correctly with canvas.

There is a vertical fixed dimensions rectangle 100w × 150h, shown as the red border below. When an image (vertical/horizontal/square) is added, and rotated, it should rotate and be scaled correctly within the vertical fixed dimensions rectangle, as shown in the example below.

In the first example, we'll go with a **vertical** image (Eiffel tower original image at 240w × 400h), this is what it should look like at all four rotation angles:[image]

In the second example, we'll go with a **horizontal** image (Dog original image at 1280w × 720h), this is what it should look like at all four rotation angles:

[image]

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this using canvas?

(I know css can be used `transform: rotate(90deg)`and play around with the background size/position properties, but I'm trying to learn how to accomplish the example above using canvas for vertical/horizontal/square images).

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/6266/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need any of the `canvas.width/2-image.width/2` code, so change your `onload` to simply by using `ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)`. Along with this you can define a global `ratio` variable that will be used for scaling correctly when you rotate sideways and need to scale upwards:

```
var ratio = 1;
image.onload=function(){
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 150;
    ratio = canvas.height/canvas.width; // We will use this for scaling the image to fit

    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Now the best way to rotate a image by it's center is to translate the image center to the `(0,0)` point of the canvas. Then you can rotate and move it back to where it was. This is because when a rotation is applied the canvas `(0,0)` point is the point of rotation.

```
function drawRotated(degrees){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);   // Move image center to 0,0
    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);                 // Rotate will go from center
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2); // Move image back to normal spot
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.restore();
}
```

With the code so far the normal and 180 degree images look fine. But the sideways ones need to be scaled upwards, to do that add in some logic to detect if the image is flipped to the left or right and then scale by the `ratio` variable (*`1.5` in this case*).

```
function drawRotated(degrees){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
    if((degrees - 90) % 180 == 0) // Is the image sideways?
        ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);  // Scale it up to fill the canvas
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2);
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.restore();
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/6258/)

***Update:***

The reason that horizontal images look odd is due to two things. Currently the scaling assumes the image needs to be zoomed in when it's sideways, in the event of horizontal images that logic is flipped. Instead we want to zoom in when we are flipped normally or upside-down:

```
function drawRotated(degrees) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ...

    if(imgRatio < 1) angleToScale += 90
    if(angleToScale % 180 == 0)
        ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);

    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2);
    ...
}
```

Here we are determining based on if `imgRatio < 1` we will claim the image is horizontal. Otherwise it will be vertical. While this is a bit broad of a stroke on claiming vertical vs horizontal, it will work for the purposes assuming we just have vertical or horizontal images.

Although even after these changes something is still off ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/6312/)). This is because when we draw the image we are fitting it to the canvas which is vertical, causing the image to stretch when it's drawn to the canvas.

This can be fixed by changing the location of where we draw the image destination. For horizontal images we want to draw it horizontally:

[image]

One note is some changes to the `onload` method:

```
var ratio = 0;
var xImgOffset = 0;
var yImgOffset = 0;
image.onload=function(){
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 150;
    ratio = canvas.height/canvas.width;
    var imgRatio = image.height/image.width;

    if(imgRatio < 1) { // Horizonal images set Height then proportionally scale width
        var dimDiff = image.height/canvas.width;
        image.height = canvas.width;         // This keeps in mind that the image 
        image.width = image.width / dimDiff; // is rotated, which is why width is used
    } else {           // Verticle images set Height then proportionally scale height
        var dimDiff = image.width/canvas.width;
        image.width = canvas.width;
        image.height = image.height / dimDiff;
    }

    xImgOffset = -(image.width - canvas.width) / 2;
    yImgOffset = -(image.height - canvas.height) / 2;

    drawRotated(0);
}
```

The `drawRotated` method is called right away to apply scaling changes. Along with that `xImgOffset` and `yImgOffset` are the difference in positions between the starting location of a horizontal and vertical canvas size in proportion to the original image dimensions.

Visually this looks something like this:

[image]

In the image above we are going to need to draw a horizontal image as the green horizontal rectangle when we draw it in our canvas. For vertical images the image is drawn with the width set to the canvas width and the height scaled proportionally with a offset so the image is centered. Likewise this is the same for horizontal images, we just need to keep in mind that we are drawing this as if the canvas is horizontal initially (*See the first figure*).

Finally the method as a whole looks like this:

```
function drawRotated(degrees){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
    var angleToScale = degrees - 90;
    var imgRatio = image.height/image.width;

    if(imgRatio < 1) angleToScale += 90
    if(angleToScale % 180 == 0)
        ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);

    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2);
    ctx.drawImage(image, xImgOffset, yImgOffset, image.width, image.height);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle For both horizontal and vertical images with original image ratio and cropping**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/6331/)

This is setup to work with any canvas dimension and size.

Comment: Thank you! That works really well on the vertical image, but I it didn't work on a horizontal image (updated question with example image). Here is your fiddle updated with the example horizontal image: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/6269/ but the image does not match the example scale wise, only the vertical one works correctly. I commented out the `ctx.scale(ratio, ratio)` but could not get it to work. What am I missing?

Comment: @Wonka That’s because I created this assuming the image is vertical. My internet just went out so I can’t update right away. But we just need to detect if the image is horizontal or vertical based on its ratio and remove the -90 to apply the scale the other way instead. Unfortunately it’s hard to code on my phone, I’ll update once my internet comes back.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Canvas is new to me and I feel it's much easier to do with css, but canvas is a different beast altogether. Awesome intro to programming profile link you got there btw, looking at canvas now and it is very helpful! Great job :)

Comment: @Wonka See the updated answer. Sorry for the delay, there was a minor caveat I had to figure out.

Comment: No worries, but I feel like for some reason the scaling is a bit off on the horizontal image, it seems to make the dog face thinner than the original rotated photo in all orientations (you can feel like it's not scaled correctly if you really focus on the dog face). Still a little confused, since your logic makes sense in terms of using numbers derived from the image/canvas and creating a ratio. Still a bit perplexed here...

Comment: @Wonka The scaling is actually not off and works as expected. The problem here is the ratio between the original image and the canvas. When it draws the horizontal image horizontally it needs to fit the image to the canvas. Since there is a decent ratio difference between the source image (`0.5625`) and canvas (`0.6667`) when it draws the whole image horizontally on the canvas it needs to be skewed to draw the entire thing. In your example you cropped the image on the left and right, here are the [two side-by-side](https://imgur.com/A4gjTZ2).

Comment: @Wonka Perhaps I miss-assumed that the images where to be fit to the canvas and drawn entirely and didn't look closely enough at your example images. In this case we just need to change the drawing to be based on the image ratios fit to the canvas dimensions rather than using the canvas dimensions. I'll see if I can make the change. Do you want the vertical images to be fitting horizontally when drawn and cropped vertically? Then vise-versa for horizontal images?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm trying to get the canvas images to match the example photos on each rotation, while maintaining the same look (so not having the image look stretched out, nor smushed in) on the canvas. So I am guessing what you're saying is that the cropped version of the image would work as intended to match the examples? I was thinking the term was more like "fill" than "fit", but I think we mean the same thing.

Comment: @Wonka I made some changes to the fiddle, before I update the answer. [Does this look correct?](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/6328/). The original vertical image also has a slight change to exactly match what was originally wanted. As far as I can tell both now match exactly to what's wanted based on keeping the same dimensions of the original image ratio.

Comment: @Wonka I went ahead and updated the answer. Hopefully this will be the final update before this turns into a book.

Comment: Very thorough answer, that's exactly what I was trying to accomplish with canvas and rotations with relation to scaling of different dimensions. You have a lot of domain knowledge, so thank you very much for sharing that knowledge and putting this answer together, it is very helpful in understanding and explaining what really happens each step of the way. One of the best answers on SO regarding this subject imho!